# Ouput and input impedance of two circuits

Tags: operational-amplifier, impedance

I would like to know if that is correct
[image: schematic1]

**Ideal Operational amplifier**

$$Z_{\text{i}}=\infty$$

$$Z_{\text{o}}=Z_{\text{c}} \parallel R$$

**741 Operational amplifier**

$$Z_{\text{i}}=2\text{ M}\Omega+R+Z_{\text{c}}$$

$$Z_{\text{o}}=Z_{\text{c}} \parallel (R+75 \Omega)\text{ (at DC)}$$

[image: schematic2]

**Ideal Operational amplifier**

$$Z_{\text{i}}=R+Z_{\text{c}}$$

$$Z_{\text{o}}=0$$

**741 Operational amplifier**

$$Z_{\text{i}}=R+Z_{\text{c}}$$

$$Z_{\text{o}}=75\Omega + (R \parallel Z_{\text{c}})\text{ (at DC)}$$

I have used plot of output resistance from LM741 datasheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using the op-amp in a closed loop configuration, any output impedance at DC is virtually zero (see my [previous](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321458/output-impedance-in-a-circuit-with-operational-amplifier/321461#321461) answer).  So, for the first circuit, when using the 741 op-amp the output impedance Zo=Zc||R.

For the input impedance, the wrong answer is Zi=2Mohm+R+Zc because the op-amp buffers the output resistor and capacitor from having any influence at the input and Zin is what the data sheet says about the 741 (typically 2 Mohm).

For your 2nd circuit, the output impedance is virtually zero ohms at DC for the reasons given in my [previous](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321458/output-impedance-in-a-circuit-with-operational-amplifier/321461#321461) answer. As frequency rises the output impedance rises.

Comment: Hi Andy I promise this is the last question, thanks in advance! https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321860/sallen-key-topology-input-and-output-impedance

Comment: That is a subtley much more difficult question to answer because of the feedback capacitor. unfortunately I'll be on a tiny and puny android for the next three days so I can't do it justice.