# Sallen Key topology input and output impedance

Tags: impedance, output, input

[image: schematic]

**Ideal Operational amplifier**

Zi=(R1+R2)||Zc2

Zo=0

**741 Operational amplifier**

Zi=(R1+R2)||Zc2

Zo=0 (at DC)

For the input impedance when using a 741 I am not sure if I should consider the Fairchild version of the 741 graph showing input resistance vs frequency impedance (at DC is about 6Mohm) so It would be Zi=((Zc2||R_OA)+R2))||Zc1+R1

Answer (score 1):

The input impedance of an opamp is that between the inputs. In the Sallen Key circuit, the amplifier is used as a follower (the other input is connected to the output), so the input impedance is 'bootstrapped out' and becomes very high within the bandwidth of the amplifier.

Even a single transistor used as an emitter follower gives very little error (except for DC offset of course) in this circuit configuration.

Comment: This is a typical configuration of a second order low pass filter, there is no a closed form expressions for Zin y Zout?

Comment: Could you please give me some reference to understand bootstraping?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd rather than me list them all, I suggest you google for 'bootstrap op amp input impedance'.